# Embedding SQL Server in JFX Application

Tags: java, sql-server, windows-installer, integration

I am developing a JFX desktop application which is working fine with sql server 2012 over a network.

My challenge is to bundle/embed the application with the database so that the user does not need have a remote server it should be a single installation. How do you go about this?

- Does Microsoft have an edition that allows for this?
- If not which Db can be used for this?

Answer (score 0):

There's a few options, Generally I would use SQL Server Express if I wanted to use a microsoft product for it, another option is SQLlite

[Documentation for SQL server express implementation on embedded database](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264562(v=sql.90).aspx)

[SQLLite with JDBC Wrapper](http://gluonhq.com/embedding-database-cross-platform-projects/)

Comment: thanks Tim for the way forward, I so far implemented SQLLite in my application for purposes to keep track of session data that I might need since the app seems to be getting big. on the two which is the best to keep more data without crushing easily for production purposes? more data would be about 2GB minimum

Comment: If it's that large of a data set, is there a reason you couldn't simply require your users to have a sql server of some sort on site? could you explain your use case as much as you're comfortable with so I can get an idea of what your expectations are going to be, because truthfully imho, that size of database is getting quite large for an embedded application.

Comment: the idea is adopted from quickbooks which is a single installation and can scale up as much, though I have not pushed its limits, I need to develop it in a way that provides comfort to me interms of its limitations. given your comment I might as well develop several versions depending on database file size

Comment: I know it's been a while but I just saw your comment... If I was you, I'd develop two versions, make one free and one paid, and on the paid version allow for data sets over the size limit and use either a more in depth solution... i know this is not a technical answer in anyway but thought i'd share my two cents, as I have quite a bit of experience in that kinda stuff.  

Also, did you ever consider using a documentdb type database?